# Angular/Spring Security Login

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an angular front end connected to an spring boot back and I need that my users can validate their id in order to access. And I really dont know why it isnt working.
Postman works just fine, I can login and everything but when i send the exact same data from my front i get an 401.

This is the login service in the front.

```
export class LoginService {
  loginUrl = "http://localhost:8080/login";
  private token!: string;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  singIn(user: LoginForm){
    let body = new HttpParams().set("userName", user.userName).set("password", user.password);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'Application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    let options = {headers: headers};
    this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body.toString(), options).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  } 
}
```

And this is my AuthenticationFilter in the back.

```
public class AutheFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AutheFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager){
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        System.out.println(userName);
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, password);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("mattAl".getBytes());
        String access_token = JWT.create()
                                        .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                                        .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000))
                                        .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                                        .withClaim("roles", user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                                        .sign(algorithm);
        response.setHeader("access_token", access_token);
    }

    
}
```

The System.out prints the username when i send it from postman, but prints "null" when is from the front. This is driving me crazy.
PD: I have already check the content-type of postman and my front, both are sending:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

in the sameformat? (i think so)

```
userName=mattp4nk&password=Matt1001
```

Does anybody know what might be happening and how do I fix it?

EDID: ADDED LOGS FROM BACK

This is the Back end log from a Postman request.

```
2022-11-01 11:30:50.106  INFO 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-11-01 11:30:50.107  INFO 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-11-01 11:30:50.108  INFO 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2022-11-01 11:30:50.120 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@74b00051, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7e59a9a3, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@46907f23, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@73d0a10d, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@5591d37c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@305c0908, com.matt.reqHandler.security.AuthoFilter@161fa322, com.matt.reqHandler.security.AutheFilter@62598b38, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@30097d5e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@9509956, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@51fe2261, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7f3a99c9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5d1bf678, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2801503d]] (1/1)
2022-11-01 11:30:50.122 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /login
2022-11-01 11:30:50.123 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
2022-11-01 11:30:50.124 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/14)
2022-11-01 11:30:50.126 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/14)
2022-11-01 11:30:50.129 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-11-01 11:30:50.129 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/14)
2022-11-01 11:30:50.131 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (5/14)
2022-11-01 11:30:50.134 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/14)
2022-11-01 11:30:50.135 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2022-11-01 11:30:50.135 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthoFilter (7/14)
2022-11-01 11:30:50.136 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AutheFilter (8/14)
mattp4nk
2022-11-01 11:30:50.138 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
2022-11-01 11:30:50.343 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2022-11-01 11:30:50.375 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2022-11-01 11:30:50.376 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

And this is the log when the post comes from my front

```
2022-11-01 11:32:15.734 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@74b00051, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7e59a9a3, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@46907f23, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@73d0a10d, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@5591d37c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@305c0908, com.matt.reqHandler.security.AuthoFilter@161fa322, com.matt.reqHandler.security.AutheFilter@62598b38, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@30097d5e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@9509956, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@51fe2261, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7f3a99c9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5d1bf678, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2801503d]] (1/1)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.736 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /login
2022-11-01 11:32:15.736 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.737 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.737 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.738 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-11-01 11:32:15.738 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.739 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (5/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.755 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.755 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2022-11-01 11:32:15.755 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthoFilter (7/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.756 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AutheFilter (8/14)
null
2022-11-01 11:32:15.757 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.763 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to find user 'NONE_PROVIDED'
2022-11-01 11:32:15.764 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : Sending 401 Unauthorized error since no failure URL is set
2022-11-01 11:32:15.765 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2022-11-01 11:32:15.765 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-11-01 11:32:15.769 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@74b00051, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7e59a9a3, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@46907f23, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@73d0a10d, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@5591d37c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@305c0908, com.matt.reqHandler.security.AuthoFilter@161fa322, com.matt.reqHandler.security.AutheFilter@62598b38, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@30097d5e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@9509956, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@51fe2261, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7f3a99c9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5d1bf678, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2801503d]] (1/1)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.770 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2022-11-01 11:32:15.770 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.771 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.771 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.771 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-11-01 11:32:15.771 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.772 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (5/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.772 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.772 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2022-11-01 11:32:15.772 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthoFilter (7/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.773 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AutheFilter (8/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.773 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (9/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.773 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (10/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.775 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (11/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.777 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2022-11-01 11:32:15.777 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (12/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.778 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (13/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.779 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (14/14)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.780 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST] - [permitAll] (1/3)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.781 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/auth/**', GET] - [hasAuthority('admin')] (2/3)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.782 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not re-authenticate AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] before authorizing
2022-11-01 11:32:15.783 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorizing filter invocation [POST /error] with attributes [permitAll]
2022-11-01 11:32:15.798 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [POST /error] with attributes [permitAll]
2022-11-01 11:32:15.799 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not switch RunAs authentication since RunAsManager returned null
2022-11-01 11:32:15.799 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /error
2022-11-01 11:32:15.805 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST] - [permitAll] (1/3)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.806 TRACE 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/auth/**', GET] - [hasAuthority('admin')] (2/3)
2022-11-01 11:32:15.921 DEBUG 9384 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Comment: Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` file to have more information about what Spring Security is doing in the logs. Activate your browser developer tools and take a look at the console to check if there is a CORS error

Comment: There is no CORS error, the rest of the services works.
I added the logs from spring security of both request to compare. Can you see something?